# Arduino GSM shield change Reset pin

Tags: arduino, gsm

I currently have a Arduino Uno and a GSM/GPRS Shield. However, I need to use the Arduino Uno pin 7 for my WIFI Shield. But GSM/GPRS Shield uses pin 7 for the MODEM RESET as well.

I know that I could change the GSM library to reroute the pin to another pin on the Arduino Uno, but it doesnt seems to be working for me.

This is the file I changed:

```
GSM3ShieldV1DirectModemProvider.cpp
```

The code that I changed is:

```
#define __RESETPIN__ 8
```

I changed it from PIN 7 to PIN 8 .

However, when I put a jumper cable FROM Arduino Pin 8 to GSM/GPRS Shield Pin 7, it is not able to send or receive data.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What GSM Shield are you using?

If it uses Sim900 module, I think you need to change the reset pin on the `GSM.h`, not in `GSM3ShieldV1DirectModemProvider.cpp`. This worked for me using the EFCON V1.2 Shield with Sim900.

Did you try change the RESET PIN in `GSM.h`, the reset `#define`? You will see the reset are on pins 9 and 8.

Comment: This looks like it should have been a commend. Could you elaborate on this more to make it a stand alone-answer?